# How to update UI immediately when running an async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webforms, async-await

I have an Asp.Net 4.5 webforms application with a report which I'm trying to run using async await. Here is an example of the code I'm using:

```
protected async void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Working!";
    await LongRunningTask();
}

private async Task LongRunningTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    lblStatus.Text = "Done!";
}
```

Everything I've read seems to suggest that the first method should complete immediately and update the label but this is not the case. The method still ties up the UI until LongRunningTask completes. If I remove async and await from btnReport_Click the UI is updated immediately but then I get an unhandled exception with no specific information when LongRunningTask completes. Please let me know what I am not understanding here.

Comment: You are not understanding that the code you showed runs on the server and has to complete before the response html is generated and sent back to client. If you don't `await` on `LongRunningTask`, the web page instance is disposed way before the execution reaches the line `lblStatus.Text = "Done!";`.

Comment: Then what is the correct way to use this in a web application?

Comment: update the text using javascript and perform a GetRequest for the longrunning task. Update the Text again when you received the response

Comment: As @Igor and Steve imply, this is not an async issue in the TAP or async-await sense at all.  You want to search for things like partial updates, AJAX, etc. instead.  I haven't done webforms for a while so there are probably more modern ways to do this now, but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx) was the idea a little while back (and might still be for webforms).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem requirement.  Solved without ajax or JavaScript and using 4.5 framework.  Here’s some advice to those that may read this:

•   Make sure your page.aspx declaration has this: `<%@ Page Title=""  Async="true"`

•   Make sure your button handler is  `protected async void MyButton(object sender, EventArgs e)`…

•   In my situation I did not use update panels although may not be a bad idea.
Basic sample code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = await GetAsyncMethod1();
        Label1.Text = s;
        //Or call this 
        //string s = await GetAsyncMethod2(); 
    }


    private string GetDataFromDB()
    {
        return  "Heres your data...";
    }

    private Task<string> GetAsyncMethod1()
    {
        //dbLayer
       return Task.Run(() => GetDataFromDB());
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAsyncMethod2()
    {
        //Optional business Layer - more processing
        string complicated = "";
        complicated = await GetAsyncMethod1();
        return complicated;

    }
```

....aspx mark-up:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" />
    </div>
    </form>
```